# Compiler won't use copy assignment instead move?

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-assignment, move-assignment-operator

I have a class where the move assignment is explicit deleted, since the object should not be moveable. But if i assign to an instance of this class using RVO the compiler gives me the error:

```
main.cpp:12:16: note: candidate function has been explicitly deleted
```

also the compiler is mentioning the existing copy assignment operator but does not use it.

here is my code (or a (not) running example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69487e46fbdfbbfa)):

```
class foo {
public:
    foo() {}
    foo(foo const& r) {}
    foo(foo&&) = delete;

    foo const& operator=(foo const& r) { return *this; }
    foo const& operator=(foo&& r) = delete;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    foo bar;
    bar = foo();
    return 0;
}
```

I found a quite similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793469/how-to-force-the-compiler-to-use-explicit-copy-constructor).

I know I can avoid this by using a temporary. i wonder why every compiler (i tested this with gcc, clang and vs2013) is not able to call the existing copy assignment directly? Is there something I am missing?

Comment: The move assignment operator is a better match. That happens before considering that it is deleted.

Comment: deleted functions take part in overload resolution.

Comment: Just don't delete the move assingment and all will be good. Presence of non-move one will inhibit the default.

Comment: out of curiosity why do you want to make the class non-moveable?

Comment: @NathanOliver Company likes slower code. :)

Comment: @erip perhaps the company measures work by counting cycles that the program consumes.

Comment: @user2079303 Hire me: `int i = 0; while(true) { i++; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The copy assignment is not called, because the (deleted) move assignment is a better match for overload resolution.

Simply don't declare the move assignment at all. Then the copy assignment will be selected. The implicit move assignment operator won't be generated because the class has a user declared copy constructor, move constructor and copy assignment operator. Any of those will prevent the generation of the implicit move assignment operator.

---

> But if i assign to an instance of this class using RVO

There is no RVO involved here. You create a temporary `foo` and copy assign it to an existing variable. Copy assignments cannot be elided.

Also, it's quite unusual and inefficient to return by value from an assignment operator.

Comment: `Also, it's quite unusual and inefficient to return by value from an assignment operator.` that's true and also the comment from erip (`Company likes slower code.`). i was working around a class not designed by me and just wondering the fact why it is happening...

Answer (score 1):

Just like `std::move()` applies a `static_cast<>()` to force the use of the move assignment/constructor, one can do something similar to force the use of the copy assignment/constructor:

```
#include <iostream>

class foo
{
public:

    foo() {}
    foo(foo const& r) {}
    foo(foo&&) = delete;

    foo const& operator=(foo const& r) { std::cout << ":)\n"; return *this; }
    foo const& operator=(foo&& r) = delete;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    foo bar;
    bar = static_cast<const foo&>(foo());
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use placement new to do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <new>

class foo {
public:

    foo() {}
    foo(foo const& r) {}
    foo(foo&&) = delete;

    foo const& operator=(foo const& r) { return *this; }
    foo const& operator=(foo&& r) = delete;
};

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    foo bar;

    //bar = foo();
    bar.~foo();
    new(&bar) foo();

    return 0;
}
```